# Pyspark - FileInputDStream: Error finding new files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Hi I'm new to Python Spark and I'm trying out this example from Spark github in order to Counts words in new text files created in the given directory :

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: hdfs_wordcount.py <directory>", file=sys.stderr)
    exit(-1)

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingHDFSWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs:///home/my-logs/")
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
              .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And this is what I get : 
[a warning saying : WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DFcn.png)

a warning message saying : `WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files`.

and I got empty results even i'm adding files in this dir :/

Any suggested solution for this ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is spark streaming will not read old files from directory..since all logs files exist before your streaming job started
so what you need to do once you started your streaming job then put/copy input files in hdfs directory either manually or by an script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/hdfs_wordcount.py) example. Are you able to run it without modifying as I see you are setting directory to "hdfs:///" in program? You can run the example like below.

For example Spark is at `/opt/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7`. You can run `hdfs_wordcount.py` available in example directory like below. We are using `/tmp` as directory to pass as argument to program.

```
user1@user1:/opt/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7$ bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/streaming/hdfs_wordcount.py /tmp
```

Now while this program is running, open another terminal and copy some file to `/tmp` folder

```
user1@user1:~$ cp test.txt /tmp
```

You will see the word count in first terminal.

Comment: Hi @abaghel, it was just a mistake while typing (i've updated my question), i'm using the exact same example, but i'm getting empty result all the time, do you think i should **spark-2.x.x-bin-hadoop2.7** instead of pulling it from *github* or something ?

Comment: You can try running sample from https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/hdfs_wordcount.py first instead of setting custom directory path in program. The results of stream processing  will be scrolling fast in other terminal so you have to watch for it as soon as you add file in /tmp directory.

Comment: it works for me now, only changing some build params :D, other question , do you think i can do something to spark to make stream even while in file change ( appending on the same logs ) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

The issue is the build, i use to build like that using maven depending on their readme file from **github** :

`build/mvn -DskipTests clean package`

I've build that way depending on their [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) :

`build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package`

Someone know what those params are ?